# AWK report formatting

Tags: bash, awk, gawk, nawk

I have a task that needs to output the result of the diags — whether it is pass "P", fail "F", halted "H". As for the `cps_ck` that is not found in the example input file, it will give me "X" meaning "not executed".

#### Sample output

```
S----------------------------------------------S
S hss_ck | meter_ck | fan_ck | ovi_ck | cps_ck S
S----------------------------------------------S
S    F   |    F     |   H    |   P    |    X   S
S----------------------------------------------S
```

#### Sample input

This is the sample content of the log file where I will extract the "P", "F",and "H". It is always in the pattern "dir to my diags" "result" "date" "time". And for this log file, the last executed diagnostic is at the end. Another challenge is that there could be two or more "hss_ck.vti" results as in my example below. What I want to get is just the latest result, which is "F" in the sample data.

```
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/hss_ck.vti  P  06-24-2015  21:00:12
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/fan_ck.eva H 06-24-2015 21:00:35
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/meter_ck.eva F 06-24-2015 21:01:16
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/ovi_ck.eva P 06-24-2015 21:02:01
/HOME/smalldir/rrim/OVICAL/ovi_cal.eva P 06-24-2015 21:32:10
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/hss_ck.vti  F  06-25-2015  01:00:12
```

The idea in my mind is like this:

1. Search for the string I want. Say "hss_ck".
2. Get the result. Should be "F" since it is the last entry for "hss_ck". But I don't know how to do it such that it only gets the result of the last entry for "hss_ck".
3. Put it in an array where my elements are the result. My array will have elements like "result of hss_ck", "result of meter_ck", "result of fan_ck", "result of ovi_ck", "result of cps_ck" and so on. So that would look like { F, F, H, P, X, } and so on.
4. Then lastly put the array in a file like `/tmp/MyArrayIsHere`.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what `Found "awk programming"` means but the best way to learn awk is from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

#### Awk program

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        o[1] = "hss_ck"; o[2] = "meter_ck"; o[3] = "fan_ck"; o[4] = "ovi_ck"; o[5] = "cps_ck"
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) a[o[i]] = "X"
    }
    { x = $1; sub(/.*\//, "", x); sub(/\.[a-z]{3}$/, "", x); if (x in a) a[x] = $2; }
    END {
    print "S----------------------------------------------S"
    print "S hss_ck | meter_ck | fan_ck | ovi_ck | cps_ck S"
    print "S----------------------------------------------S"
    prefix = "S"
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        len = length(o[i]) / 2
        printf("%s%*s%s%*s", prefix, len, " ", a[o[i]], len+1, " ")
        prefix = "|"
    }
    printf "S\n"
    print "S----------------------------------------------S"
    }' data
```

Outline:

1. Set up column names in the sequence (order, hence `o`) they're to be printed.
2. Initialize states in array `a` to `X` (not executed).
3. For each line of input, extract code from `$1`; if the code is one of the interesting ones, save the value of `$2` in `a`.  The latest value overwrites the previous value.
4. Print the table heading (ugly format, but that's what the question asks for).
5. For each row, print the value of the states in the required order, being careful to align things.  Note that it depends on the lengths of the codes being 6 and 8 (both even numbers).  You have to work harder if one of the codes is an odd length.  Not that much harder, but harder.  Also note that the heading line could be generated from the data in `o` instead of being hard-coded.
6. Finish up the output.

#### Example data

```
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/hss_ck.vti  P  06-24-2015  21:00:12
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/fan_ck.eva H 06-24-2015 21:00:35
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/meter_ck.eva F 06-24-2015 21:01:16
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/ovi_ck.eva P 06-24-2015 21:02:01
/HOME/smalldir/rrim/OVICAL/ovi_cal.eva P 06-24-2015 21:32:10
/home/bigdir/subdir/os/i686_linux_2.6.9/diags/hss_ck.vti  F  06-25-2015  01:00:12
```

#### Example output

```
S----------------------------------------------S
S hss_ck | meter_ck | fan_ck | ovi_ck | cps_ck S
S----------------------------------------------S
S   F    |    F     |   H    |   P    |   X    S
S----------------------------------------------S
```